# NatGeo Photo RSS feed?

Tags: rss, photo, feed

So, NatGeo used to have an RSS feed for Photo of the Day [feed link](http://feeds.nationalgeographic.com/ng/photography/photo-of-the-day/), that I received in main through ifttt, however it was discontinued in August.
Since then I've been using Bing but wanted to look into natgeo as well.
As a half measure, I am using a feed from Your Shot tumblr, but the content is not quite the same.
So the question is: is there a publicly-available NatGeo photo of the day feed? Preferably with no additional scraping need, and one I can redirect to my email.
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please explain what you tried...add some code, show examples and explain the problem. 
This is not a code request forum. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for learn how you can improve your question. You can check too in [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Check this link in [NatGeo rss news](http://feeds.nationalgeographic.com/ng/News/News_Main)  or check directly the [Photograpy of the Day](http://www.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day/) link. You have to use YQL or other web crawler for get these results...

Comment: Yep, the main RSS feed for news still works. I was hoping to avoid running my own crawling query to simplify maintenance of such a simple activity.